# Writing Ranges into formulas with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using variable ranges, and want to insert those ranges into a formula that can be saved in a document that does not use VBA.

Do I have to use a with statement?

My If Statement works until I try and insert a relative range. I searched and didn't see much on this, so this issue is probably so simply I am an idiot.

The program will be doing things all over the worksheet, so relative coding is needed. The number of items in the range changes with each iteration. I will be using an end range integer [myRange] for the number instead of 10, but I wanted to simplify what I am struggling with into the smallest steps.

```
    Dim Test As String
    Test = "=IF(COUNTIF(" & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Address & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(10, 0).Address & "" _
            & ")," & """Not Complete""" & "," & "" & """"")"
    ActiveCell.Formula = Test
```

Desired output in target cell:
"=IF(COUNTIF($J$3:$J$12),"Not Complete","")"

Comment: you are missing the second criterion in the COUNTIFS() and just do: `,""Not Complete"","")` on the end.

Comment: `Test = "=IF(COUNTIF(" & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Address & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(10, 0).Address & ",""test""),""Not Complete"","""")"` replace `""test""` with your criteria.

Comment: `COUNTIF()` requires two criteria, a range and the item to count in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your `COUNTIF` statement is currently invalid. What are you counting in the range `J3:J12`? This needs to be added (in place of `"CRITERIA"` in below solution) before your equation will be valid

```
Test = "=IF(COUNTIF(" _
        & ActiveCell.Offset(1).Resize(10).Address(True, True) _
        & ",""CRITERIA""), ""Not Complete"", """")"
```

---

*If you want your output to actually have the quotes you can output
`Chr(34) & Test & Chr(34)` which seems cleaner than wrapping the whole string in quotes from a readability point of view IMO*